# how to have outlined text field's focused style as default text field style?

Tags: android, xml, material-ui

I want to have this focused style as my default(unfocused) style:
[image]

And when focused, I want it to change the color.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have been searching for a while but found nothing yet.